# User defined TYPE across databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a database that holds common functions that I use across multiple databases. One of these functions takes in a table as a parameter which is a user defined TYPE. I would like to know if there is a way to call this function from another database.

I tried to define the type in the other database like so:

```
DECLARE @bits as Common.dbo.Bits
```

However I received an error too many prefixes

I have tried adding the TYPE to each database, and then passing a table of that type to the function in the common database, but there I get an error of

> Operand type clash: Bits is incompatible with Bits

Comment: can't you create all the needed types in the other databases, as part of the db first-setup process?

Comment: @vulkanino I can, but as I have seen, they are not the same type

Comment: It's funny, almost a year later and I came back to this same error. This time it was different schemas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Even if you declare the type identically in two databases, they're not treated the same. And the `DECLARE` statement is only allowed a schema name and an object name, so there's no way to reference a type from another database.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531769/passing-table-valued-parameter-to-stored-procedure-across-different-databases/9532187#9532187) for some possible work arounds (if you control both databases involved)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the answer I wanted to hear. Thank you

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Isn't this strange of Microsoft to do? It's kind of like saying that in C# you can't use a class from a file unless it's on a file inside your current directory?

Comment: @Kulingar - if you're working in two different assemblies, and you create two types with identical (full) names and members, you still can't substitute one for the other (directly).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the answer that keeps on giving, this has been causing me some headaches the last hour.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Creating User-Defined Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933121(v=sql.80).aspx):

> If a user-defined data type is created in the **model** database, it
>   exists in all new user-defined databases. However, if the data type is
>   created in a user-defined database, the data type exists only in that
>   user-defined database.

Comment: That's true about the Model database, but I don't think that they are the same type. Besides, I am working with existing databases.