# Use UDT with specified database in a document that use another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I use the the current database named test

```
USE [test]
GO

DECLARE @test [dbo].[work]

in the file named tt.sql

DECLARE @test [dbo].[work]
```

It works

However, if I use the code `"DECLARE @test [dbo].[work]"` only

in another document that use another database (USE [abcd]) named abcd

then I need to add [test].[dbo].[work] but it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581749/user-defined-type-across-databases

Comment: Check [Using User-defined Types Across Databases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178069%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)